# Silent installation for apt-get

Tags: apt, gnupg

For work I have to prepare a lot of PCs. I have to shove bunch of `sudo apt-get install` commands into the terminal - that's quite tedious.  I could probably put all of them into sh script (maybe), but some of the commands require adding new repository (`sudo add-apt-repository`) or adding new key (??) via `gpg` command - and they require the user to press ENTER.

Any way to to say "yes" to all or something? This would probably require adding some options to apt-get and gpg commands?

Comment: Did you take a look a the respective manual pages of these tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barring a custom install of a pre-configured system, I'd probably go with an install script run on each system.

What are the commands that need to press enter? `add-apt-repository`'s help advertises it's `-y` option:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository --help
Usage: add-apt-repository [options] repository

Options:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -y, --yes   force yes on all confirmation questions
```

The help link below says that for adding PPA's "If a public key is required and available it is automatically downloaded and registered." There are also packages like `ubuntu-keyring`, `ubuntu-extras-keyring`, `linuxmint-keyring` etc that contain the keys for various repositories. And `man gpg` should tell how to get it to automatically install a key, if you're stuck using it.

And/or you could edit the `sources.list` files directly with `sed`/`awk`, or if the systems are identical just copy over the "finished" files.
This Ubuntu help page has more info on [how to manage software repositories from the command line.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine)

And if you're preparing a lot of systems, can I assume you'll only be downloading the .deb packages once, and installing them all to each machine, instead of updating then downloading them all for every system? If you have all the .deb's in one folder this command would install all of them:

- `sudo dpkg -iR [deb-directory]`

FYI, I used to see one odd package that would wait for an <kbd>enter</kbd> before finishing installing, apparently it was inside one of it's own config scripts, and even `apt-get`'s `--force-yes` wouldn't work with it. You don't have any of that type, do you?

---

Or, if you're intent on just **force-feeding a bunch of keystrokes** into a telnet (should work for other methods too) terminal, you could use a bash script like this one:

```
{
echo "open 192.168.55.55"
sleep 0.5
echo "$login"
sleep 0.5
echo "$password"
sleep 0.5
echo "command1"
sleep 2
echo " "
sleep 5
echo "exit"
} | telnet
```

Using different sleep times for delays between "typing", echoing a space with `" "` or even just echo should send a newline "return".

Answer (score 2):

You can append the `--assume-yes` and `--force-yes` flags to automatically say yes to all.

`sudo apt-get --assume-yes --force-yes install <packagename(s)>`

To make these changes permanent, edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and add the lines

```
APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";    
APT::Get::force-yes "true";
```

This is what the man page of [`apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt-get) says -

```
   -y, --yes, --assume-yes
       Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
       run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
       changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
       package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will
       abort. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

   --force-yes
       Force yes; this is a dangerous option that will cause apt to
       continue without prompting if it is doing something potentially
       harmful. It should not be used except in very special situations.
       Using force-yes can potentially destroy your system! Configuration
       Item: APT::Get::force-yes.
```

Comment: `add-apt-repository` has `-y` and `--yes` flags for the same purpose.